# urllib and “SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” Error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, url, matplotlib, beautifulsoup

I have written a program in which I want to request a website to read but the program causes a certificate problem and I couldn't solve.Though I have searched and read some article but I find nothing. I think my problem is unique.Thanks.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
for s in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(s.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests module`

**Demo:**

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
sauce = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.content, 'lxml')
for s in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(s.string)
```